# Puppeteer Header and Footer have different scale than content

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer, chromium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpwyS.png)
I use puppeteer for generate an invoice PDF.
I have a template that is render with nunjucks, I set the content with the puppeteer page function setContent
I have defined a header and a footer, same thing I generate the template with nunjucks

When I render the PDF (await page.pdf(...)) the scale of the header and the footer are larger than the content. The font-scale is 12px and it's larger on the header/footer, same thing for the margin.

Anyone alreay have the issue ? How to fix it ?

I want to have the same scale on header/footer than the content

Here some code:

```
const html = nunjucks.render(QUOTE_TPL, { $t: i18n.__, quote: foundQuote, linesByPages, keys, fullWidthHeader, currency: '', format: formatPrice, moment, pdf: true, headless_mode });
    const footerHtml = nunjucks.render(QUOTE_FOOTER, { $t: i18n.__, quote: foundQuote })
    const headerHtml = nunjucks.render(QUOTE_HEADER, { $t: i18n.__, quote: foundQuote, moment })
    // Convert HTML quote to PDF
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.emulateMediaType('print')
    await page.setContent(html);

    const filePath = path.resolve('./tmp/' + file_name + new Date().getTime() +'.pdf');

    await page.pdf({
      path: filePath,
      format: 'A4',
      displayHeaderFooter: true,
      headerTemplate: headerHtml,
      footerTemplate: footerHtml,
      margin: {
        bottom: '80px',
        top: foundQuote.style.header.height + 80 + 'px',
      }
    });

    await browser.close();
```

And here an example of the header template:

```
<div style="
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 21cm;
    position: relative;
    background: #00c1af;
    padding: 0;
">
    {% if quote.display_rules.title != null %}
    <div class="invoice-title {{quote.display_rules.title}}" style="
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
            font-weight: bold !important;
            color: #212529 !important;
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale !important;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            font-smooth: always !important;
            font-size: 15px;
            top: 2cm;
            right: 2cm;
        ">
        {{ quote.title }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="invoice-header" style="
        background: #ffff00;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 1.9cm);
    ">
        {% if (quote.style and quote.style.header and quote.style.header.image) or (quote.company_logo) %}
        <div class="logo-wrapper {{fullWidthHeader}}" style="height:{{quote.style.header.height }}px;margin:{{quote.style.header.margin}}px">
            {% if headless_mode !== 'true' %}
            {% if quote.company_logo %}
            <img class="logo" src="{{ quote.company_logo }}" alt="" style="position: relative; width: auto;height: 100%;max-height: 100%;"/>
            {% else %}
            <img class="logo" src="{{ quote.style.header.image }}" alt="" style="position: relative; width: auto;height: 100%;max-height: 100%;"/>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="invoice-name" style="
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
            color: #212529 !important;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale !important;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            font-smooth: always !important;
            font-weight: bold !important;
            font-size: 15px;
        ">
            <span>
                {{ $t('documents.' + (quote.language or 'fr-FR') + '.' + quote.name.trim()) }} {{ quote.number }}
            </span>
            <span class="invoice-date">
                {{ $t("documents." + (quote.language or 'fr-FR') + ".from") }} {{ moment(quote.date).format($t("date." + (quote.language or 'fr-FR') + ".format")) }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I had the JS part, for QUOTE_TPL is a full template html with tag html, body ... and for QUOTE_FOOTER and QUOTE_HEADER it's just a div (I tried with a full tag html, body too but it's the same)
Thank's for answer me

Comment: I think the problem is the header is consedering larger than the content. I just define a div with text in my header in position absolute top right and we can see the text out of the pdf, we only see the begining.

Comment: Anyone ? 
If it's not an clear answer just some leads could help, I tried so many things I'm lost on this

Comment: @Ayme Curious if you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post and this is more of a **hack** than a real answer. If anybody came up with a proper solution, I'd love to know.

When generating an **A4**-format PDF, the dimensions of the PDF are **210mm x 297mm**.

---

My header looks as following:

```
<div class="header">
    <span>Arial 14px</span>
</div>

<style>
    /* #header is the ID that is added by Chromium, do not use it in your template or rename */
    #header, html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 210mm;
        height: 47mm; /* in my case, the header is 47mm in height */

        /* this is the hack, figured out by try and error*/
        transform: scale(0.90804);
        transform-origin: left top;
        /* end of hack */
    }
    .header {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        width: 210mm;
        height: 47mm;
        box-shadow: -0 -0 4mm 0px red inset; /* this is for visualization only */
    }
    .header span {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
```

---

And then my PDF body looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
            @media print {
                body {
                    box-shadow: -0 -0 4mm 0px blue inset; /* this is for visualization only */
                }
                html, body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    width: 210mm;
                }
                body > span {
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-family: Arial;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    margin: 0;
                    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Arial 14px</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the outcome, both texts "Arial 14px" should look the same. I hade some case where I refreshed the generating page and the outcome was slightly off by one pixel.

Oh, and I have also set the top-margin in my page.pdf() options:

```
const pdfOptions = {
    path: 'path-to-my.pdf',
    preferCSSPageSize: true,
    format: 'A4',
    printBackground: true,
    margin: {
      top: '47mm',
      right: '0mm',
      bottom: '4mm',
      left: '0mm'
    },
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    headerTemplate: `{{headerTemplate}}`,
    footerTemplate: `{{footerTemplate}}`
};
```